# Equivalent of extend method of collection in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I use user defined type like 
create type type_name table of (varchar2(32000));

In oracle and to extend the size of that type i used extend method of collection 
type_name.extend();

but now i am converting the oracle database to postgresql and i m using user defined type and i want to extend the size of that type so which method i used to extend the size of that type in postgresql.

I try various method like unnest and append but they are not working please tell me alternative of extend method...

Comment: Without knowing what you actually want to do with that, it's nearly impossible to answer. But in general, collections in PL/SQL would translate to arrays in PL/pgSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: PostgreSQL's arrays don't need an `extend` function. You can just [assign a value to an index, which does not exist yet](http://rextester.com/WCFLVA79865), or [use some array manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), like `array_append(anyarray, new_element)`